# HTML5 semantic structure for a navbar

Tags: html, navbar, semantic-markup

How should I code my navbar, with semantics in mind?

I've been advised to nest everything in `header` and then nest links in `nav`, but I don't feel like this is the right way to do it.

```html
<header>
<h3>Developer's Blog</h3>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Press</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

or

```html
<nav>
<h3>Developer's Blog</h3>
    <div>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Press</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: In the latter, your h3 is a heading of the nav section. Is that what you intended it to be?

Comment: This is just an example, I'll probably use h1 with a smaller font-size.

Comment: In semantics terms, that makes no difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `nav` element is, of course, the correct choice for the navigation.

Any heading element (`h1`-`h6`) inside of it is for the navigation itself, not for the page. So something like "Navigation". But if it’s the only navigation, you’d typically don’t need a heading for it.

You might want to use a `ul` inside of `nav`, with a `li` for each navigation link. By using block-level elements like this, user agents without CSS support (e.g., text browsers) display one link per line; currently your links would be displayed all in the same line. And by using a list, screen reader users have more options to *navigate* the navigation.

If the `nav` should be part of your `body`-`header` can’t be answered generally. Both ways are possible; that’s one of the more subjective areas of markup choice.

So HTML5 markup for the typical/common site-wide `nav` would be:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/press">Press</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: There won't be any viewers that will use text browsers and I'm totally sure about that. How about the `h1` element? How should I implement it? It's a typical navbar with a logo on the left side and links on the right side.

Comment: @noczesc: Depends on what the `h1` is for. If it’s the site name (e.g., the logo) it shouldn’t be part of the `nav` element. For that heading, the nearest section should be the `body` element. If you want a heading for that navigation (e.g., "Navigation") then simply place it anywhere in the `nav`.

Comment: Let me use an example - http://prntscr.com/apx558 is what I'm going for.

Comment: @noczesc: If you mean "Developer’s Blog": This seems to be the site name, so it should be a `h1` in the `body` sectioning root. Don’t place this in the `nav`. So the section-relevant elements would be: `<body><h1>Developer’s Blog</h1> <nav></nav> <article><h2>IT Teams: Luxury or Necessity?</h2></article> </body>`